# Cannot use using construction to connect to SQL Server in UWP application

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, using, sqlconnection

I have such errors:

[image]

or description who don't want to use link:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in
>   'System', but it could not be
>   found Reporting_UI_UWP    C:\Users\beloh\Desktop\OLSOM\AVOA\AVOAReport\VS_0.1.0\Reporting_UI_UWP\SQL\SQL.cs   33  Active
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7069  Reference to type 'ICloneable' claims it is defined in
>   'mscorlib', but it could not be
>   found Reporting_UI_UWP    C:\Users\beloh\Desktop\OLSOM\AVOA\AVOAReport\VS_0.1.0\Reporting_UI_UWP\SQL\SQL.cs   33  Active

when write that's code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(defConnString))
{
}
```

defConnString is defined and System.Data.SqlClient imported.

When I'm use that code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(defConnString);
```

all is ok.

What's the problem?

Comment: What version of the Windows SDK, Visual Studio (incl. update number) and NETCORE nuget package are you using in your project?

Comment: Target version: Win 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)
Min version: Win 10 November Update(10.0; Build 10586)

VS: Community 2017 version 14.11.25325 debug and 14.10.25008.00 release as I understand

NETCore  version 6.0.1

Comment: Minimum version for supporting NET Standard 2.0 in UWP is 16299. Does it work  if you change the min version accordingly?

Comment: Yeah, It's working, for now, thx a lot. Maybe you could share some basics link?

Comment: I have posted an answer summarizing the requirements and some links. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario to work, you need the following configuration:

- Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 (or later)
- Min version in your UWP project 16299 (=Fall Creators Update)
- NETCore version 6.0 (or later)

Here is a [sample app](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/IgniteDemos/tree/master/NorthwindDemo).

Here is the [session](https://myignite.microsoft.com/videos/53541) at Microsoft Ignite 2017 where we demo'ed it.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlConnection` lies in `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace which is not available in UWP.

You can only use the APIs for UWP apps provided by Microsoft. Refer to [Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/).

Comment: Not true. With Fall Creators Update UWP supports .NET Standard 2.0 and as a result also System.Data.SqlClient.